# Многопоточность и ассинхронность

Tags: java, многопоточность, асинхронность

Пытаюсь понять что такое асинхронность.
Ранее смотрел несколько статей\видео по этому поводу, но с каждым последующим просмотром - совсем запутался.
В одном видео говорилось про то что

**потоки** - это подобие дополнительных рабочих, но их проблема в том что пока работает один поток другие ожидают его окончание.

**асинхронность** - это возможность давать команды на выполнение определенного кода,и в этот момент может паралельно выполнять свои задачи.

На этом объяснении я завис.
Когда я писал сервер\ клиент. В сервере организовывал несколько потоков которые выполнялись паралельно. У меня был метод в левом потоке на количество клиентов подключенных к серверу, поток для подключения новых клиентов, и главный поток.

Может это все происходит слишком быстро и это не замечается, объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Прежде всего надо разобраться с терминологией. В самом простом виде программа выполняет **последовательно** или синхронно, инструкция за инструкцией, в том порядке, в котором они идут в коде.

```
System.out.println("A");
System.out.println("B");
System.out.println("C");
```

Каждый вызов `println` **блокирующийся**. Это значит, что пока он не закончится, программа не будет выполняться дальше.

В реальном мире от программы требуется реагировать на множество событий,  происходящих в произвольные моменты времени, или одновременно выполнить задачи существенно более долгие, чем вывод на экран. Такое выполнение называется **многозадачным**. Но в этом месте часто возникает путаница, так как вместо этого часто, особенно в мире Java, используют термин "**асинхронное** выполнение", а у этого термина есть своё значение, более конкретное.

Чтобы лучше разобраться в истинном значении терминов, приведу бытовую аналогию:

- Один человек ставит кастрюлю на плиту, ждёт пока она закипит, закидывает пельмени, ждёт пока сварятся, снимает, ставит вторую, ждёт пока закипит... - последовательное однопоточное выполнение.
- Один человек ставит две кастрюли на плиту, как только одна из них закипела, забрасывает пельмени и т.д. - асинхронное выполнение.
- Два человека ставят две кастрюли... - многопоточное выполнение.

В данной аналогии плита - это аппаратный ресурс (процессор), пельмени - программный ресурс (сокеты), человек - это поток, а кипение - блокирующийся вызов.

> **Примечание:**
>   К аналогии можно добавить ещё вариант "Два человека ставят две
>   кастрюли на две плиты", описывающий действительную параллельность в
>   многопроцессорной системе. Но с описанием видов многозадачности можно
>   легко выйти за ограничение по количеству символов на ответ.

Очевидно, что при асинхронном выполнении ресурсов требуется меньше, а скорость та же, что и при многопоточном. Именно поэтому [проблему c10k](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k) могут решать только асинхронные сервера. Минусы в том, что асинхронный код зачастую сложнее и не всё можно выполнять асинхронно.

В вашем прошлом вопросе я уже показывал примеры многопоточного и асинхронного кода:

**Многопоточный код**

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
while (true) {
    // Вызов accept() блокирующийся и остановит цикл до тех пор
    // пока не поступит новое соединение
    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
    // При этом будет запущен отдельный поток, который будет
    // обслуживать только это соединение
    executor.execute(() -> {
        // Отправка файл, которая займёт 5 секунд например
    });
    // Выполнение продолжится сразу после вызова execute,
    // меньше чем через миллисекунду. Если подключится ещё один
    // клиент, для него будет запущен ещё один поток, и будут
    // передаваться два файла одновременно двум разным клиентам.
}
```

**Асинхронный код**

```
serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
while (true) {  // Цикл событий
    selector.select();  // Мультиплексирование
    Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = keys.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = iterator.next();

        if (key.isAcceptable()) {  // Поступило новое соединение
            SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            // Регистрируем его для обработки в этом же потоке
            // на следующих итерациях цикла
            socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, new Storage());
        }

        if (key.isReadable()) {  // В одном из соединений появились данные
            SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);

            // Читаем столько данных, сколько сейчас есть
            int read = socketChannel.read(buffer);
            if (read != -1) {
                ...
            }
            else {  // Ничего не прочиталось, значит пора закрывать соединение
                socketChannel.close();
            }
        }

        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

В примере асинхронного кода нет ни одного блокирующегося вызова, цикл никогда не останавливается. Какой вариант многозадачности выбрать - это вопрос имеющий смысл только в контексте конкретной задачи. У каждого варианта свои плюсы и минусы. Из примеров видно, что асинхронного кода требуется больше, но при асинхронном выполнении значительно реже возникает ситуация, когда [два человека  дерутся](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) за одну пустую кастрюлю, пока в другой [догорают пельмени](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: Здравствуйте, вопрос по этой строке.
        serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
Как должны создаваться serverSocketChennel  и Selector ?

Я пробовал 2 варианта. В методе 1) - 
ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;
Selector selector;

В итоге ошибки, и idea мне предлагает инициализировать.
ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = null;
Selector selector = null;
Но ошибка остаеться. 2) - Так же пробовал вынести эти строки в тело класса, но ошибка осталась

Comment: На ваш прошлый вопрос я ответил готовыми к компиляции примерами, вы можете посмотреть в них, как создаются `serverSocketChennel` и `selector`.

Comment: Спасибо, будем разбирать =)

Comment: Две поправки. 1. один блокирующий вызов все-таки есть, это `selector.select();`, без него цикл был бы очень грустным :-) 2. мультиплексированием все-таки называется не вызов select, а последующий цикл по selectedKeys и серия проверок isAcceptable / isReadable

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, действительно так. Я для простоты решил опустить эти детали.