# Многопоточность VS Асинхронное программирование

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность

Итак, дабы раз и навсегда разобраться с этим: задам вопрос еще раз.
[Прочитав](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-vs-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), все равно непонятно каким образом надо писать тех же ботов.
Если

> Асинхронность (asynchrony) подразумевает, что операция может быть выполнена кем-то на стороне: удаленным веб-узлом, сервером или другим устройством

То это абсолютно ломает мои познания в асинхронности питона, ведь читал я о ней абсолютно другие вещи.

Итак. Возьмем практический пример:
У меня есть бот для *ВКонтакте* на чистом питоне. Обмен информации идет через `CallBack API`. При получении
сообщения оно кладется в статическую переменную:

```
if data['secret'] == environ['secret_key']:
   payload = None
if data['object'].get('payload'):
   payload = json.loads(data['object']['payload'])['button']
StaticData.stack_messages.append({'message': data['object']['text'], 'user_id': data['object']['from_id'],'payload': payload})
StaticData.new_message_trigger.set()
return 'ok'
```

После складирования активируется триггер `StaticData.new_message_trigger.set()` и после все действия происходят в основном `хэндлере`:

```
@staticmethod
def handle() -> None:
    logging.info('Messages handler started')
    while True:
        try:
            vk = BotAPI()
            IDB = InternalDB()
            StaticData.new_message_trigger.wait() # Ждем изменения состояния триггера
            StaticData.new_message_trigger.clear() # Состояние изменилось, очищаем его

            data = StaticData.stack_messages.pop(0) # Получаем проброшенное через статику сообщение
            # Other actions...
```

Сама архитектура кажется мне очень запутанной и неправильной. Так ли это? Если да, то как хоть примерно преобразовать это в асинхронную структуру?

Comment: [Ответ про Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816006/204271), но наверняка почитать вам его будет интересно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Многопоточность джавы понятно, а вот с асихнронностью. Вообще она в разных яп по разному существует. Обожаю асихнронность в `JS`, но ненавижу в `Питоне`.

Comment: Асинхронность везде одинаковая - кооперативная многозадачность с переключением контекста на вводе/выводе. Разница только в нюансах реализации.

Comment: Асинхронность далеко не всегда подразумевает "выполнение на стороне". https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-vs-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1534872#1534872