# Выполнение метода Java во время выполнения долгого запроса в бд Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Подскажите, есть ли способ реализовать подобный кейс:
Выполняется соединение с бд и последующий запрос (условный SELECT). Если же попытка соединения висит больше 10 секунд, то текущую сессию не обрывать, но выполнить сторонний метод (логирование - метод реализован уже, тут вопросов нет).
Получается, что нужно во время попытки соединения с бд при превышении определенного времени параллельно выполнить логирование такого запроса не обрывая самой сессии.

Comment: Кто тебе сказал,что это *нужно*?

Comment: Я сам себе сказал) Для реализации определенной функциональности мне требуется подобный механизм работы.

Comment: Вопрос требуется оформлять должным образом. Для того нужно почитать [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: видимо, речь про [Многопоточность и ассинхронность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/815998/178576)